# How do I create an input that will only receive int() values?

Tags: python, python-3.5

The methods that I have used up until this point have involved try/except, if statements and while loops, but they have not given the desired result. They either keep on allowing strings or producing an exception or not allowing any entry.

```
Age2 = input('Age (Numbers Only):') #3
while type(Age2)!=type(1):
    print('\nPlease define Age in numbers only\n')
    Age2 = input('Age (Numbers Only):')
```

I am also uncertain how to add a limit that prohibits the user from entering the age: 0 into the system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether `age2` is an instance of `int`. :

```
age2 = input('Age (Numbers Only):')
while not all([age2 > 0, isinstance(age2 , int)]):
    print('\nPlease define Age in numbers only\n')
    age2 = input('Age (Numbers Only):')
```